# Passing a LinkedList value to a function - C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a file having four columns of 10 test data and these data will be stored in four variables to a `linkedlist`.

```
struct node
{
        float proxy;
        float planAdded;
        float actualAdded;
        float devHours;

        struct node *next;
}*head = NULL, *current = NULL;
```

My objective is to have a one function to calculate sum and average of those 10 data so that i don't have to have four separate `calcsum` functions.

How to pass these values separately to a `calcSum` function?

For example if i need to find the sum of proxy how to pass this to the function?

```
float calcSumX(nodeT *head, head->value)
{
        current = head;
        float sum = 0;
        while(current != NULL)
        {
                sum += current->x;
                current = current->next;
        }
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly you can pass the head of the node and offset of the values you want to sum for each node e.g: calcSum(node, offsetof(node, proxy)) offsetof(node, devHours) etc.

Comment: can you provide the definition of the `nodeT` structure?

Comment: @LukasBernreiter nodeT is the typedef of the above mentioned node

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then this is what you are looking for:

You can just create an `enum`, which defines the desired member and pass it to the function. The function then gets the appropriate member accordingly to the value of the `enum`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
  float proxy;
  float planAdded;
  float actualAdded;
  float devHours;

  struct node *next;
} node; 

node *head = NULL, *current = NULL;

typedef enum {proxy, planAdded} member_op;

float getMemberValue(member_op op)
{
  if (op == proxy)
    return current->proxy;
  else if (op == planAdded)
    return current->planAdded;
  else return 0;
}

float calcSumX(node *head, member_op op)
{
  current = head;
  float sum = 0;
  while (current != NULL)
  {
    sum += getMemberValue(op);
    current = current->next;
  }
  printf("sum: %f\n", sum);
  return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
  node *first = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  node *second = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  node *third = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

  first->proxy = 1;
  second->proxy = 2;
  third->proxy = 3;

  first->planAdded = 4;
  second->planAdded = 5;
  third->planAdded = 6;

  first->next = second;
  second->next = third;
  third->next = NULL;

  head = first;
  calcSumX(head, proxy);
  calcSumX(head, planAdded);

  free(first);
  free(second);
  free(third);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot boss. Worked fine :) except i had to have `typedef enum member_Op member_Op;`, without it an unknown type name error occurred. Thanks a lot :)